# Send form data to functions.php

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a hidden input form,which has my custom product price.
I want each time i add new item to cart this price(form) which is dynamicly generated with javascript to be sent to functions.php using $_POST

Code :

**HTML**

```
<input id="hiddenfield" type="hidden" action="functions.php" value="foo" 
     name="hiddenfields" />

        <?php echo do_shortcode('[add_to_cart id="212"]');   ?>
```

**JS FILE**

function totalprice(){

```
var one=Number(document.getElementById("vol1").value);
var two=Number(document.getElementById("vol2").value);
var three=Number(document.getElementById("vol3").value);
var four=Number(document.getElementById("vol4").value);


var total=one+two+three+four;

var target=document.getElementById("final");

target.innerHTML=total +"€ VDC/ month";
```

**FUNCTIONS.PHP**

```
 add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals',
 'woocommerce_pj_update_price'
 , 99 );

function woocommerce_pj_update_price()  {
$custom_price = 100;   
$target_product_id = 212;


    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        if($cart_item['data']->get_id() == $target_product_id){

            $cart_item['data']->set_price($custom_price);


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The answer is AJAX. Each time the totals are calculated, send the form data to the wp ajax handler.

**Step 1:** pass your ajax URL from PHP to javascript using wp_localize_script just after you enqueue your script file.

```
wp_enqueue_script('myScript', 'my/script/path.js');
wp_localize_script('myScript', 'php_params', ['ajaxurl'=>admin_url('admin-ajax.php')]);
```

**Step 2:** make the AJAX call in your script.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: php_params.ajaxurl,
    data: {
        action:'mytag_function_name',
        your:'data', 
        goes:'here'
    },
    success: function(data){
        // do something
    },
    error: function(errorThrown){
        // do something
    }
});
```

**Step 3:** add the ajax method to your functions.php file

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_mytag_function_name', 'mytag_function_name' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_mytag_function_name', 'mytag_function_name' );

function mytag_function_name(){
    // do something with your $_POST data
    $post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
    echo "Here's my result to get returned to Javascript";
    die();
}
```

Learn more about AJAX in the WordPress Codex:
https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i just noticed that each time something is added to cart the old price is getting overwritten too. For example:
Added to cart product 1 with price 100
Added to cart product 1 with price 200

first price (100) becomes 200 too  How can i fix this?

Comment: In your foreach loop you are setting the price of each item to $custom_price. You declared $custom_price outside of the loop so this is why all your cart items end up with the same price. Try moving your $custom_price calculation inside of the foreach loop so it's calculated for each item.